# Is it normal for the Fujifilm HS25 to have high resistance to zoom?

Tags: zoom, fujifilm, bridge-camera

I bought the 35mm "dslr emulator" on a trial basis. Attracted to hand-zoom lens as motorized zoom is the "weak link" (in terms of camera mean time between failure) on motorized non-dslrs (where entire camera is not lost when zoom fails).

I did not expect that hand zoom twisting would be other than ultra-smooth... like a high quality scope. What is the general experience with this camera's zoom smoothness? Other such cams? How decide whether to keep or to return camera?

Camera is 30x/60x with fine focus ring.

Answer (score 3):

The HS30 EXR has a very smooth zoom and the HS25 EXR with which it shares the lens should be identical. If there is resistance I can only assume some stuff got into the mechanism. I also have an X-S1 which has a tighter zoom because it is weather sealed but I still would call it smooth and shows little resistance. On all these cameras the zoom can be operated without jerking the camera.

*Me too I prefer mechanical zoom but for other reasons: infinite precision, quiet, smooth and fast. Now I can add one more :)*

Comment: ThnkY. I had though possible some clash fromm finefocus ring - and manual did seem to suggest. But no

Comment: ThnkY. I forgot about 5 minute comment compose time. Here's with corrections. I had thought possible some clash from finefocus ring - and manual did seem to suggest. But no relative repositioning makes difference in "gross" focus smoothness. Looks like back to store, swap and try another. Thank Goodness Costco generosity on such matters.